# Clean way to show data from an API grouped?

Tags: javascript, html, object, fetch, data-manipulation

I am using an API which gives me 70-ish projects. From these projects I need to show the title, image and tagline on a website. I managed to get the data on the website, but right now it shows the data as follows:

- Titles
- Images
- Taglines

Which means that right now I'm seeing 70 titles, then 70 images, then 70 taglines. I, of course, want this to be shown per project, so one title, one image, one tagline. This then should repeat for every project.

My code:

```
function fetchProjects(url) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            appendData(data.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

function appendData(data) {

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let h3 = document.createElement('h3');
        h3.innerHTML = data[i].project.title;
        document.getElementById('project__header').appendChild(h3);

        let img = new Image();
        img.src = data[i].project.header_image;
        document.getElementById('project__image').appendChild(img);

        let p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = data[i].project.tagline;
        document.getElementById('project__tagline').appendChild(p);
    }
}

fetchProjects('api_url');
```

I tried reformatting my code but that didn't work. I also tried Googling this but I didn't get any results that could help me, so I probably didn't use the right keywords. My apologies.

Can anyone point me to a clean way I can achieve this in plain Javascript and HTML? Thanks!

EDIT: Of course I don't want to have to make 70 unique ID's and solving it like that, I know it's possible but it's definitely not the clean solution I'd presume

Comment: sounds to me like a poor API. A good API will let you select the parameters it should return.

Comment: I was able to select that I only want the titles, images and taglines to show. There is more to every project but I'm not using the other properties. My problem lies in showing the data. If titles are A, images are B and taglines are C, right now it's showing like this:

AAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC

And what I want is this:

ABC
ABC
ABC
ABC

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop, you're appending the items to the same element, so if you have:

```html
<div id="project__header"></div>
<div id="project__image"></div>
<div id="project__tagline"></div>
```

after two cycles you'll have

```html
<div id="project__header">
  <h3>...</h3>
  <h3>...</h3>
</div>
<div id="project__image">
  <img ... />
  <img ... />
</div>
<div id="project__tagline">
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

You should append them to the same element, or create a div and then append the entire div, something like:

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");

const h3 = document.createElement('h3');
h3.innerHTML = data[i].project.title;
div.appendChild(h3);

const img = new Image();
img.src = data[i].project.header_image;
div.appendChild(img);

const p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = data[i].project.tagline;
div.appendChild(p);

document.getElementById("...").appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

you append all the titles to the 'project__header' div, images to the 'project__image' div, and tag-lines to the 'project__tagline' div. If I do this, it could be

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // create a div container for each project
        const dataDiv = document.createElement('div');

        const projectTitle = document.createElement('h3');
        projectTitle.innerHTML = data[i].project.title;
        dataDiv.appendChild(projectTitle);

        
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = data[i].project.header_image;
        dataDiv.appendChild(img);
    

        const projectTag = document.createElement('p');
        projectTag.innerHTML = data[i].project.tagline;
        dataDiv.appendChild(projectTag);
     
        // append the dataDiv to the parent container (use your own DOM element) of the projects
        parentDiv.append(dataDiv);
        
    }
```